# The server tag is not well formed error after migrating the code to ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: .net, vb.net, data-binding, asp.net-4.0

I have the following piece of code which works fine on VS2008 and .NET3.0, but fails after migrating to VS2010 and .NET 4.0

I am getting an error:

> Server tag is not well formed

Below is the code, please advice!

```
<td valign="top" align="center" class="CRMtdLabelSingleColNoBold">
   <input id="radCustomAuditType" name="<%#"AuditType"%>" type="radio" runat="server" value="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "audit_type_code") & "," &  If(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "custom_audit_survey_id") IsNot DBNull.Value, DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "custom_audit_survey_id").ToString(), "") %>" "<%# iif(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AuditType") = True And CheckBoxCustomAuditType = True, " checked=""True""", "")%>" "<%# iif(CheckBoxCustomAuditType = False OR DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "audit_type_code").IndexOf("WYTWS-") <> -1, " disabled=""disabled""", "")%>" "<%# iif(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "audit_type_code").IndexOf("WYTWS-") <> -1, " WYTWS=""true""", "")%>"/>  
</td>
```

Comment: Could you take a minute to make your code a little more readable (by human beings)?  That is a really long input element.

Comment: You might try removing what appears to me to be an extra set of double-quotes here: `name="<%#"AuditType"%>"`

Comment: Look like cat walks on your keyboard. That kind of logic should be placed inside the bound event.

Answer (score 4):

You should implement this logic into a C# function in the code behind, maybe implementing the `Bound or Bind event`.

Any way looks like you need to replace double quotes for single one in `name` and `value`:

```
<input 
id="radCustomAuditType" 
name='<%# AuditType %>' 
type="radio" 
runat="server" 
value='"<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "audit_type_code") &&  
         If(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "custom_audit_survey_id") IsNot DBNull.Value, 
            DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "custom_audit_survey_id").ToString(), "") %>" 
            "<%# iif(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AuditType") = True And 
             CheckBoxCustomAuditType = True, " checked=""True""", "")%>" 
            "<%# iif(CheckBoxCustomAuditType = False OR 
             DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "audit_type_code").IndexOf("WYTWS-") <> -1, " disabled=""disabled""", "")%>" 
            "<%# iif(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "audit_type_code").IndexOf("WYTWS-") <> -1, 
        " WYTWS=""true""", "")%>'
/>
```

Comment: you're a saint for having the patience to wade through that code.

Comment: I realy dont know if this will really work, theres a bunch of ifs there... i need more code! This legacy ASP code sux!